# Trying to understand how some function works

Tags: r, function, loops, sorting

I was given a task to write a function, which I name: `my_mode_k`.

The input is consisted of two variables:

```
(x, k)
```

as `x`, is a vector of natural numbers with the length of `n`. the greatest object of `x` can be `k`, given that `k < n`.

my_mode_k output is the highest frequency object of `x`. if there's more then one object in the vector that are common in `x` the same number of times - then the function will output the minimum object between them.

for example:

```
my_mode_k(x = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3) , k =3)
1
```

This is code I wrote:

```
  my_mode_k <- function(x, k){
  n <- length(x)
  x_lemma <- rep(0, k)
  for(i in 1:n){
    x_lemma[i] < x_lemma[i] +1
  }
      x_lem2 <- 1
      for( j in 2:k){
        if(x_lemma[x_lem2] < x_lemma[j]){
          x_lem2 <- j
        }
      }
      x_lem2
}
```

which isn't working properly. 
for example:

```
my_mode_k(x = c(2,3,4,3,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5), k=5) 
[1] 1
```

as the function is supposed to return `5`.

I don't understand why and what is the intuition to have in order to even know if a function is working properly (It took me some time to realize that it's not executing the needed task)  - so I could fix the mistake in it.

Comment: Your input is `x` and the elements that are subject to testing should be smaller (and equal to?) than `k`. Frequency of these elements is calculated and output should provide the number with greatest frequency. If there is a tie, minimum of those is returned. Does that sound right?

Comment: yes! thankyou! @RomanLuštrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few steps on how you can achieve this.

```
k <- 5

input <- c(2,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5)
# Calculate frequencies of elements.
tbl <- table(input[input <= k])
# Find which is max. Notice that it returns the minimum of there is a tie.
tbl.max <- which.max(tbl)
# Find which value is your result.
names(tbl.max)

input <- c(2,2,3,3,3,5,5,5)
names(which.max(table(input[input <= k])))
# 3

input <- c(2,2,5,5,5,3,3,3)
names(which.max(table(input[input <= k])))
# 3
```